# Upgrade to HTTP/2 for subsequent requests after Windows Authentication

Tags: iis, microsoft-edge, chromium, http2

We have a number of web apps running where the initial authentication is done using NTLM/Kerberos to save users logging in if they are logged into Windows using their own credentials.   Following this, authentication to the APIs etc... is done using a cookie.

I understand HTTP/2 doesn't support Windows Authentication, but once the browser has downgraded to HTTP/1.1, we can't seem to get it to switch back to HTTP/2 again.   We are using Edge Chromium (long story, are unable to change) - and I have read that there is an HTTP/1.1 header that should allow upgrade, but I can't get it to work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade

I have tried having the Upgrade header set to 'HTTP/2.0', 'HTTP/2', and h2c, but none of them work.    I have also tried adding a request header called 'http2-settings' as per another article that I read, but this didn't work either.

Keen to hear if anyone has had success getting a Chromium based browser to upgrade to http2 once it has served some http/1.1 requests.

Thanks

Comment: What you observed is the reality, so no way to bend it. You'd better get rid of Windows authentication, because it now offers less and less benefits.